# Wireless geo-nodes connection

Tags: geometry-nodes

How do I make the connection between the nodes "wireless"? Example in the screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This feature doesn't exist currently. It is however discussed by the developpers. See https://devtalk.blender.org/t/portal-links-exploration/21306

Comment: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/portal-links-exploration/21306 Thanks to Gorgious. This feature doesn't exist currently.

Comment: hey that's pretty interesting and yeah that makes alot of sense to have these node portals. i'm sure they will implement this in the future. I semi-use this "feature" with the Group input node by duplicating the group input so i don't have to draw wires across the entire node structure.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options here:

### Variant 1

Here, you simply place your geometry into a node group, allowing you to reuse it in different places in your node tree.

The disadvantage is, however, that this geometry is created and evaluated several times, which may be important for an extensive project, but can be neglected for simple things:

[image]

### Variant 2

Here you put the geometry simply into an own Node group, apply this however before on an independent object.

You can then use this object with `Object Info` in your node tree as often as you like.

Note that you should/must activate the option *As Instance* here:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: +1 ! i did not read it but i know it must be correct :D

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie ...Thank you for your unconditional trust! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then click <kbd>RMB</kbd> and drag it across the noodle then release to cut the connection.

[image]

Comment: No, that's not what I'm talking about.
(Arrr... Ma anglih iz weri gut... )

I want to connect the "Geometry" output to the Group Input. To then connect this "geometry" across the map using the "Group Input" node without stretching a bunch of lines across the all tree.

Send second screen on top.

Comment: mach mal auf deutsch XD

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie ...Woar jo eh deitsch! ;-)

Comment: ah guck mal einer an dat ist der geomeister der muss die antwort wissen! :D

Comment: @quellenform Aufhören, das ist doch kein deutsch :D

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann OK, einigen wir uns auf "westgermanisch" :D

Comment: @quellenform Aber nur gerade noch so...  :D